# Automatic image build detection failed. Error: Component map not found. Consider adding a Dockerfile to the workspace and try again

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I'm using **Visual Studio Code** with **Cloud Code** extension. When I try to "**Deploy to Cloud Run**", I'm having this error:

> Automatic image build detection failed. Error: Component map not
> found. Consider adding a Dockerfile to the workspace and try again.

But I already have a Dockerfile:

```
# Python image to use.
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy the requirements file used for dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Install ptvsd for debugging
RUN pip install ptvsd

# Copy the rest of the working directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Run app.py when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "ptvsd", "--port", "3000", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "manage.py", "runserver", "--noreload"]
```

How to solve that, please?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to repro the issue, but I checked in with the Cloud Code team and it sounds like there could have been an underlying issue with gcloud that wasn't your fault.

I don't think you'll see this error again, but if you do, it would be awesome if you could file an issue at the [Cloud Code VS Code repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode) so that we can gather more info and take a closer look.

This does show that we need to improve our error messages though. I've filed a bug to fix messaging regarding this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but after connecting in a different network and running the commands below, the error is gone.

```
gcloud auth revoke
gcloud auth login
gcloud init
```